# react-router-dom nested routes and redirects

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, framer-motion

I'm trying to expand a bit on the nested routes example over at react training in the [quick start guide](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-test-ubpjp

In the code sandbox browser, if you navigate to /some - this works, then click SomeOne - this also works. However, clicking "SomeTwo" which should redirect to "Some" loads blank, why?

Also, those links fail to work right off the bat? There might be some strange stuff in the sandbox as I've been hitting it with random stuff to try and get it working.

I just want to structure the routes such that I don't have to have all of these routes in one file.

I've done a lot of searching and have tried a lot of different kinds of implementations, but all of them end up having issues / problems, either with adding a catch-all route, or redirects.

Removing the props from the Switch worked, but this breaks the AnimatePresence from framer-motion.

Following the example of framer-motion at: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-x-react-router-n7qhp?file=/src/index.js

The redirect still fails, even with the withRouter hook on the Navigation and redirect component.

Comment: As I checked, it work normally, what is your issue?

Comment: It works? For me, in the example, if I navigate to /some, then click "SomeOne" then click "SomeTwo" it loads blank, the redirect doesn't load the component, but then a refresh makes it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not pass any props to Switch component. Also make sure that you are rendeing `Navigation` component as a Route or use `withRouter HOC`, so that it received Router props.

```
    <Switch>
        {children}
    </Switch>
```

[image: Edit FORM VALUES]

Comment: Switch component requires those props so that framer-motions AnimatePresence can detect change - this is in their docs as an example for this setup. Interesting, removing the props from Switch does fix the issue... I guess this is something I should raise against framer-motion.

Comment: Can't re-edit previous comment. The example I refer to from framer-motion is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-x-react-router-n7qhp?file=/src/index.js - it has been updated since I last looked at it and I have adjusted the sandbox to match, but the redirect still fails. Have added withRouter hook to the navigation and to the redirecting component.

Comment: Will have a look

Comment: https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/606 and https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/466 it's a known bug, and the workaround at https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/466#issuecomment-596279963 worked for me. Accepting your answer because I wouldn't have gotten further without your help there!